# I'm trying to draw polyline on coordinates(lat, long) coming from API using swift 3 in map kit but unable to make polyline

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkitannotation

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import AddressBook

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var TheMap: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        zoomToRegion()
        location()
    }

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: MKPointAnnotation, regionRadius: Double) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
                                                                  regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        TheMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

    }



    //MARK:- MapViewDelegate methods

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)

        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5

        }
        return polylineRenderer
    }



    //MARK:- Zoom to region

    func zoomToRegion() {
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.618945, longitude: 77.377347400000005)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 5000.0, 7000.0)
        TheMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    // API CALL FUNCTION

    func location() {

        let user = "userid"
        let password = "password"

        let postString = ["empid":user, "date1": password]
        var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string: "http://mydomainhere.com/airtel_hrm/webapi/api/getpunchdeytails")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options:.prettyPrinted)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?)in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
                    let data = json["punchdetails"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    //print(data)

                    for datas in data {
                        let lat  = datas["punch_loc_lat"] as! String
                        let long = datas["punch_loc_long"] as! String

                        var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

                        let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(lat)
                        let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(long)
                        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                        annotations.append(annotation)


                        self.TheMap.addAnnotations(annotations)
                        self.TheMap.delegate = self

                        self.centerMapOnLocation(location: annotations[0], regionRadius: 2000.0)

                        // Connect all the mappoints using Poly line.

                        var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [coordinate] //[CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

                        for annotation in annotations {
                            points.append(annotation.coordinate)
                        }

                        print("this is points = \(points)")

                        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

                        //self.TheMap.add(polyline)

                    } //for loop closed

                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        task.resume()


    }

}
```

Comment: In the future, rather than just dumping a ton of code on us, also share info about what debugging you did and share what output your `print`/logging statements generated.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, by convention, variables names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. I'd rename `TheMap` to `mapView` or something like that). Maybe don't tackle that until you solve the problem with the above code (we don't want to introduce another variable in the process), but just a suggestion for the future.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'm new to iOS, not having much idea about that and surely learnt for future. Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure if you shared the results of the `print` statement, the problem would have been obvious. You're probably seeing lots of print statements. Bottom line, you should define your array *outside* of the `for` loop, only `append` values within the loop, and then add the polyline after the loop:

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any],
        let data = json["punchdetails"] as? [[String: Any]] {

        var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

        for datas in data {
            let lat  = datas["punch_loc_lat"] as! String
            let long = datas["punch_loc_long"] as! String

            let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(lat)
            let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(long)
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotations.append(annotation)
        }

        self.TheMap.delegate = self  // you really should do this in IB or, if you feel compelled to do it programmatically, in viewDidLoad

        // Connect all the mappoints using Poly line.

        let points = annotations.map { $0.coordinate }

        print("this is points = \(points)")

        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.centerMapOnLocation(location: annotations[0], regionRadius: 2000.0)
            self.TheMap.addAnnotations(annotations)
            self.TheMap.add(polyline)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note, I'd also do all interaction with the map view from the main queue.

Comment: Thanks! this code worked. all points are connected to each other. is it possible to connect only two points at a time not all ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "two points at a time". Do you mean you want to see it animate as draws the path or something like that? If that's what you're looking for, rather than just adding the full poly line, I'd create a timer or something like that, which, as _k_ advanced from 2 to _n_, I'd (a) create poly line from point 1 to point _k_; (b) add that to the map; (c) remove the prior poly line. (Note you might be inclined to remove the prior one first, but IIRC, that can yield a flickering effect; if you add new one before removing old one, that is diminished.)

Comment: I want to connect these points like I have points a,b,c,d,e my initial point is a and final point is e, so i want to connect a to b, b to c, c to d and d to e like route path. How can I do this any suggestions Please